# myFunction is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery

in my `scriptfile.js` I layout a simple text re-sizing function. On its own, the function works as expected. However, when I try to add `$(window).resize(fitheadliner());` to my scriptfile to fire the the `fitheadliner()` function on the resize event, it get a "Uncaught ReferenceError: fitheadliner is not defined" error. I have moved the resize function around the scriptfile thinking it may be a scope issue to no avail. Here is the contents of the file:

```
( function( $ ) {

  $.fn.fitheadliner = function() {
    this.each(function() {
    var
      $headline = $(this),
      $parent = $headline.parent();


    var
      textW = $headline.width(),
      parentW = $parent.width(),
      ratio = parentW / textW;

    var
      originalSize = parseFloat($headline.css('font-size')),
      newSize = originalSize * (0.9 * ratio);

    $headline.css("font-size", newSize);

    });
  };
  $(window).resize(fitheadliner());

} )( jQuery );
```

Comment: You have `$(this)` 5 times, once should be sufficient. Do you want to pass *fitheadliner* to *resize*, or the result of calling *fitheadliner* (which is what you are trying to do).

Comment: Same error with and without the () on fitheadliner

Comment: @PHPglue—you mean it takes a function reference.

Comment: It would be `$(window).resize($.fitheadliner)` because `.resize()` takes a function reference. Also, `fitheadliner` is now a jQuery property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not quite a scoping issue.  More like a qualification issue.

When this line executes

```
$(window).resize(fitheadliner());
```

You are saying, run `$(window)`, then run `fitheadliner()`, then run the `.resize` method of the return value of the first call, passing it the return value of the first function call.

It's easy to think that the manner in which you are calling `fitheadliner()` would tie it to the `$` object, but it doesn't.  There's no reason it would.  Each expression is evaluated independently and then chained appropriately.

Therefore, this expression is looking for a symbol in scope named `fitheadliner` that must be of type `function`.  There are no symbols in scope with that name.  There is, however, a symbol named `$.fn.fitheadliner`

To get past this error, you need to *fully-qualify* the reference, like

```
$(window).resize($.fn.fitheadliner());
```

But the fact is, I don't think that is totally what you want either.  `.resize` takes a handler function.  `fitheadliner` does not return a function, or return anything.  It actually does some work.  So I think what you meant to do was to pass a *reference* to `fitheadliner` to `resize`.

That's easy - take the paranthesis out.

```
$(window).resize($.fn.fitheadliner);
```

Now, even better, there is probably no reason to attach `fitheadliner` to the jQuery prototype like that.  Try this.  It may more closer to what you were trying to do.

```
( function( $ ) {

  function fitheadliner() {
    this.each(function() {
    var
      $parent = $(this).parent(),
      $headline = $(this);

    var
      textW = $(this).width(),
      parentW = $parent.width(),
      ratio = parentW / textW;

    var
      originalSize = parseFloat($(this).css('font-size')),
      newSize = originalSize * (0.9 * ratio);

    $(this).css("font-size", newSize);

    });
  }
  $(window).resize(fitheadliner);

} )( jQuery );
```

This defines a function in scope called `fitheadliner` and then passes a reference to it to `resize`.

Personally, I would take it one step further and inline the function anonymously since it does not need to be reused.  But it's a matter of form/preference for me.  There's semantically no difference.

```
( function( $ ) {

  $(window).resize(function fitheadliner() {
    this.each(function() {
    var
      $parent = $(this).parent(),
      $headline = $(this);

    var
      textW = $(this).width(),
      parentW = $parent.width(),
      ratio = parentW / textW;

    var
      originalSize = parseFloat($(this).css('font-size')),
      newSize = originalSize * (0.9 * ratio);

    $(this).css("font-size", newSize);

    });
  });

} )( jQuery );
```

Comment: Now my call to the function fails due to a `TypeError` here: `<script type="text/javascript">jQuery("#responsiveHeadline").fitheadliner();</script>`

Comment: Ok, so the function is called elsewhere and is expected to be part of all jquery objects.  So go with the third code sample I posed.

Comment: Then it gives me a `Uncaught TypeError: this.each is not a function` error :/

Answer (score 4):

Here:

```
$.fn.fitheadliner = …
```

*fitheadliner* is defined as a property of *$.fn*.

But here:

```
$(window).resize(fitheadliner());
```

you are attempting to access it as a variable (and call it). Consider:

```
(function($) {

  function fitheadliner() {
    ...
  }

  // Assign a reference, don't call the function
  $(window).resize(fitheadliner);
}(jQuery));
```

However, you have  a further issue from:

```
this.each(function() {
```

The function is called with *window* as *this*, and *window* doesn't have an *each* method. I don't understand how you aren't seeing other errors (or erroneous behaviour). Perhaps *this* should be replaced with a selector:

```
$(<selector>).each(...);
```

Comment: Now my call to the function fails due to a TypeError here: <script type="text/javascript">jQuery("#responsiveHeadline").fitheadliner();</script>